# What is the simplest way for me to expand this program to calculate the inverse of up to a 10x10 matrix?

Tags: c++, c++11, matrix, matrix-inverse

The program I have below finds the inverse of only a 3x3 matrix, but I'm wondering if there is a simple way for me to expand it to find the inverse of a user entered sized matrix UP TO 10x10. Thanks

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int mat[3][3], i, j;
    float determinant = 0;

    cout<<"Enter elements of the matrix:"<<endl;
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
           cin>>mat[i][j];


    //finding determinant
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        determinant = determinant + (mat[0][i] * (mat[1][(i+1)%3] * mat[2][(i+2)%3] - mat[1][(i+2)%3] * mat[2][(i+1)%3]));


    cout<<"\n\nInverse of matrix is: "<<endl;
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            cout<<((mat[(j+1)%3][(i+1)%3] * mat[(j+2)%3][(i+2)%3]) - (mat[(j+1)%3][(i+2)%3] * mat[(j+2)%3][(i+1)%3]))/ determinant<<"\t";

        cout<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The simplest method to compute the inverse of a matrix is the [method of Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Gaussian_elimination). I would recommend using it for any matrix that is larger than 3 x 3.

Comment: Essentially, you need to pick a suitable algorithm that is designed for inverting a matrix of arbitrary order (or, at minimum, for inverting up to a 10x10 matrix).   Starting with a special case (3x3) and extending it won't work, since there are shortcuts possible in smaller special cases that are not possible for larger order matrices. There are plenty of descriptions available of how to do matrix inversion using determinants, for matrices of arbitrary order.  Practically, techniques using determinants are often less numerically stable than simple alternatives, such as gaussian elimination.

Comment: Not really a problem with c++ itself.... its just a simple algorithm you need to implement...
Take a look at https://www.c-plusplus.net/forum/289905-full

Answer (score 1):

Or are you actually asking "how would I structure this" to support matrices up to 10x10? You could write yourself a class that is constructed with the dimensions, internally sizes a vector, and externally publishes an array operator method to act as the outer array dimension.

```
class SquareMatrix
{
  std::vector<int> storage;
  unsigned int innerSize;
  SquareMatrix(unsigned int innerSize):
    innerSize(innerSize),
    storage(innerSize*innerSize,0)
  {}
  int* operator[](size_t index)
  {
    /* please do some error checking */
    return storage.data()+index*innerSize;
  }
};
```

You can declare an instance of this matrix, after you have input the dimension, and then use it just like you are using your 3x3 matrix, but you would need more scaffolding outside to count up to the sizes and ensure you don't exceed the dimension.

Ideally, it would be better if the array index operator returned another object containing both the pointer to the inner array, and the maximum dimension, so its array operator can error-check again.

And the proper object-oriented answer is your inverse function should be a member of your matrix class.

And yes, you are going to have to work that math down to do more columns and rows.